# Seems to be a bug in support design library

Tags: android, android-support-library, kotlin, android-support-design, anko

I'm trying to create an application with similar to `Google Photos` app UI. Support Libary Version = 25.1.0.

The problem in that with translucent status and navigation bars, widgets inside `CoorinatorLayout` looks not as expected. Setting `fitsSystemWindows=true` attribute for the `BottomNavigationView` makes it too large (screenshot 1) and `SnakBar` in that case appears behind navigation bar, not above `BottomNavView` or nav bar as expected. If I add `fitsSystemWindows=true` in `Toolbar` (screenshot 2) then BottomNavigationView looses it's `fitsSystemWindows` attribute and `Toolbar` content gone somewhere. It looks as a support library bug, but I'm not sure in that.

Here is my DSL code:

```
       coordinatorLayout {

                customToolbar {
                    id = TOOLBAR
//                  fitsSystemWindows = true
                    title = createTitle(ctx)
                    lparams(matchParent, dip(48))
                }

                frameLayout {
                    id = CONTENT_FRAME
                    backgroundResource = R.color.colorBackground
                    lparams(matchParent, matchParent)
                }

                bottomNavigationView(R.style.Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark) {
                    id = BOTTOM_NAVIGATION_VIEW

                    fitsSystemWindows = true
                    itemIconTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ctx, R.drawable.nav_item_color_state)
                    itemTextColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ctx, R.drawable.nav_item_color_state)
                    backgroundResource = R.color.colorAccent
                    inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_drawer_2)
                    lparams(matchParent) {
                        anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
                        anchorId = CONTENT_FRAME
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image][image]

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not using the latest support libraries? Also, do you have any custom theme defines under values/styles.xml ?

Comment: Screenshot 1 - the bottom bar is not too large. It's supposed to extend behind the navigation bar if it's translucent. /// Try wrapping the Toolbar in an AppBarLayout with fitsSystemWindows instead.